# Launching Fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-nested-fragment

In my **MainActivity**, I have a viewPager
containing two containers "A and B".
Both containers are possessed with their own Fragments.

In container B; I again have a **viewPager** containing multiple fragments.(*For example one,two,three,four*)

On launch of my app MainActivity gets load with container A's homeFragment.

What I need to do is,For a given condition I have to launch **fragment two** of container B from onResume of my MainActivity.

What I've able to achieve is , I have successfully redirect to *container B's* **fragment one** but couldn't able to redirect towards **fragment two** from onResume of MainActivity, any help will be appreciate.

Comment: mb in oncreate fragment B start fragment two?

Comment: it is based on a condition , I can't launch fragment two everytime when fragmentB is called, coding in onCreate wont help

Comment: Is **Container B** supposed to contain multiple `Fragment`s simultaneously?

Comment: does your fragment one of B required to be in stack

Comment: newInstance add paramether startTwoFragment and in oncreate verify

Comment: @SlashG indeed , it has a viewPager with multiple fragments

Comment: @DrupDesai no,when we are going through the given condition it could be negligible  .

Comment: So, it's a nested `ViewPager`. First of all, it could be troublesome for a user to swipe because of this nesting.

Nonetheless, you want, upon this condition, to open Fragment 2 by default from `onResume()`?

Comment: @SlashG yes a nested ViewPager,one in MainActivity, other in ContainerB, swipe are managed without troublesome. And exactly,on a condition I want fragment2 to open bydeafult from onResume() of MainActivity.

Comment: I think Kurlicue's answer would work for you, then. Just put that code in the `if` block of your condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly,I found a way of achieving this by using static concept.
I have declared a static variable inside container B's fragment two,and set its value in onResume of MainActivity.

When onResume calls with given condition it sets static variables value to the required fragment, and in my container B,I have used this value to set setCurrentItem() of B'viewPager.

ps: I know it quite confusing as it seems but not too complex in practice,work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intent to redirect to Fragment B, then pass the int position of sub fragment, and on the fragment B side check for intent extras and set the current page, which you received via intent.getIntExtra().

Comment: I am not using intent in my main Activity as I mentioned,I have viewpager so am using viewPager's method setCurrentItem(here_passed_position_B) to launch containerB.

Comment: @AnuragPandit how u create fragment?

Comment: A work around, create a public static int in Fragment B as current item = 0; 
set it to the position you want, before you call setCurrentItem() redirecting to Fragment B.

So when the fragment B is selected it will setCurrentItem(currentItem); ByDefault it would be zero, or the first page.. may be not the perfect ans, but a solution may be. :P

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it clear, you want to show the second page of the viewpager when you open it, if so you can use `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);`

Comment: How can I access container B's viewPager from onResume() of MainActivity.

Comment: You don't have to, if you're already starting B on `onResume()` you can just put this in B's onCreate

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the specific page .. so to do that you can set viewpager as :

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(item, true);
```